# Question: Regarding GridView boundfield ReadOnly property

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview boundfield where i set ReadOnly to true because i don't want user to change its value. However on the objectdatasource control's update method that boundfield became null when i try to use it as parameter in update method. Is there a way to set that value during updating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mark a field as read-only on the GridView it renders on the page as a span element, not an input.  Therefore the value is not available on PostBack.  If you can construct the update statement so that it doesn't expect this field, that would be the best way to deal with this.  If the update statement is autogenerated and you can't get around having the value to update, then you can either read the value from the database before doing the update (so that you have it) or include a HiddenField bound to this column and use a literal that obtains the value via Eval instead of binding (if necessary).  This will require using a template.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="itemTextBox" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="itemHF" Value='<% Bind("Item") %>' />
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="itemLabel" Text='<% Eval("Item") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="itemLabel" Text='<% Bind("Item") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me a lot. though this answer is pretty old i want to give an additional info: you dont need an additional hiddenfield, using a label and bind the "Item" to it will provide the same functionality. You also dont need the EditItemTemplate if you just want the field to be readonly

Comment: @Fender - the label value won't get posted back.  The purpose of the hidden field is when the update method requires the value but you don't want the user to be able to change it.  I am aware that there are issues with doing it this way -- the user could spoof the post, changing the value, for example -- so you'd need to be careful about the context in which you're using it.

Answer (score 5):

No, just add the field name you need to the DataKeyNames attribute of the GridView.  Then the value will be sent to the Update command.

Comment: thanks Barry although this is an old post it help me out appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add a new query to your tableadapter. Create an update query that just uses the fields desired to be updated. When selecting the update method on the ODS pick the update query. The BoundFields that are not part of the update query can now be turned to readonly=true and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it in a slightly different way.  But in my case the parameter I wanted to use in my Update method was my primary key and was available in a Query string.  So in my DataSource definition I defined the UpdateParameters section to use  instead of .  Then I was able to remove the parameter completely from my table and it would revert to the Query string parameter.